copying a dope sheet
hey all a quick question actually I have a tree leaf animation in dope sheet of blender when I copy the leaf trees to another blender file it only copy the object but the dope sheet is empty , is there a way to copy the whole object with the dope sheet animation to another blender file? thanks in advance 


How are you copying them? - If you use File > Append, you will see there's a Mesh folder and an Action folder in your original file (plus a Texture folder which you'll also want). The Action folder should include an action named the same as the tree mesh and appending both should bring the animation in with the mesh.
